# How and where to store metadata in oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, triggers

I'm having multiple business tables in my Oracle 12c DB that look like:

```
Table A { col_A1, col_A2, ..., created, last_updated }
Table B { col_B1, col_B2, ..., created, last_updated }
...
```

Those tables do not have anything in common besides the fact, that every row has stored the values when it was created and last updated.

I personally think that this is bad design, just like in networking, where multiple protocols have to define fields for IP and port to address the target.

**What I want:** The columns *created* and *last_updated* should not appear in any of my business tables. I still want to store these values for each row in every table tho.

**What came across my mind:** Create a table (let's say META_TABLE) to store *created* and *last_updated* referencing the ROWID of the original row. Create triggers *AFTER UPDATE* and *AFTER INSERT* for every business table to fill up META_TABLE.

**What I don't like about this:** To create triggers for every created table and for every table that I have to create in the future.

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I personally think that this is bad design". You're right. It's the worst design, Except for all the others.

Comment: Have you considered using the [built-in auditing options](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm)?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole, I'm looking into it and will see if it fits my needs.

Comment: So, question for this bad design?  What happens when you want to export this data, or for some reason, you need to restore the table from a backup?  You've now split the data into two tables, with your tables "meta-table" data mixed in with every other tables "meta-table" data.

Comment: Thing twice how good is your „good“ design. Any DB user manipulating any of your tables must have access rights to the meta table. How can you secure that each DB user manipulates only the meta records belonging to tables that are granted to this user??

Comment: A bigger problem seems to be that `rowid` can change, so export/import or some other activities could break the link between the 'meta data' and the data it relates too.

Comment: I understand all your points, but i just don't know how to do better. Any other suggestions?